# Event Data is undefined after confirmation modal has been clicked

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, dom-events

I have a dropdown from the semantic-ui package, which works fine when I don't include the confirmation modal code in my project. This is what I currently have:

```
<Dropdown
      loading={settingConfig}
      disabled={!configEditable}
      options={configs && configs.length > 0 ? configs.map(formatConfig) : teltonikaConfigs.map(formatTeltonikaConfig)}
      onChange={this.handleConfigChange} />
      <EditButton editingEnabled={configEditable} onClick={this.toggleConfigEdit} />
```

The options are formatted in the following way:

```
const formatConfig = conf => ( { key: conf.id, text: conf.name + '-' + conf.scriptVersionId + '.' + conf.configVersionId, value: conf.id, image: getRisk(conf.risk)} );

const formatTeltonikaConfig = conf => ({key: conf.id, text: conf.name, value: conf.id});
```

When an option is selected, the following function is called:

```
handleConfigChange = ( e, data ) => {
    const forceUpdate = true;
    // Not an Atom B Device
    if (this.props.device.type !== "HARDWIRED-BM") {
        const configId = data.value;
        this.setState( { settingConfig: true, configEditable: false } );
        updateConfiguration(this.props.device.imei, configId, forceUpdate)
            .then( this.props.handleDeviceUpdate )
            .catch( error => toast.error( "There has been an error whilst updating the device.. This will need to be updated manually. " + error.message ) )
            .then(() => this.setState( { settingConfig: false } ) )
    } else {
        const configId = data.value;
        console.log(" Id " + configId);
        this.setState( { settingConfig: true, configEditable: false } );
        updateTeltonikaDeviceConfig(this.props.device.imei, configId, forceUpdate)
            .then(this.props.handleDeviceUpdate)
            .catch(error => toast.error("There has been an error whilst updating the device.. This will need to be updated manually. " + error.message))
            .then(() => this.setState({settingConfig: false}))
    }

};
```

This will then get the configId from `data.value` as per the formatted configs and works fine...

However, when I add a confirmation dialog/modal so when the user selects an option, they have to confirm yes or no, `configId/data.value` is undefined. The code for this is as follows:

The dropdown changes to this (onChange method changes):

```
<Dropdown
   loading={settingConfig}
   disabled={!configEditable}
   options={configs && configs.length > 0 ? configs.map(formatConfig) : teltonikaConfigs.map(formatTeltonikaConfig)}
   onChange={this.show} />
   <EditButton editingEnabled={configEditable} onClick={this.toggleConfigEdit} />
```

I also have this code to show the dropdown:

```
    show = () => this.setState({ open: true })

handleConfirm = (e, data) => {
    this.handleConfigChange(e, data);
    this.setState({ open: false })
}

handleCancel = () => this.setState({ open: false })
```

Then the confirmation dialog code is as follows:

```
 <div>
   <Confirm
   open={this.state.open}
   cancelButton='No'
   confirmButton="Yes"
   onCancel={this.handleCancel}
   onConfirm={this.handleConfirm}
 />
 </div>
```

So from this, when an option is selected, the dialog window opens and when the user clicks `YES` `e,data` is sent into the `handleConfirmMethod`.. Now my problem is that data contains the following values, and not the `configId` which is passed through without the confirmation dialog:

[image]

The data passed through is that of what is in the confirmation dialog code.. Can someone please help me with this, as I need to pass through the configId as data?

Hope this makes sense!

Comment: Hi, the data here is the data from the `<Confirm />` component, you might want to pass a new `data` object to the `handleConfirm` and then handle it in the `handleConfigChange`, if you could send a codesandbox link i could help you debug

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot get configId(data.value) from handleConfirm because, handleConfirm is a callback function which is fired when you click the "yes" button on `<Confirm/>`, it has no idea of which option you just selected. The only place you can get that information is the onChange callback on that `<Dropdown/>`.

To solve your problem, we need to pass the configId(data.value) from `Dropdown`'s onChange callback to `Confirm`'s onConfirm callback. There are several solutions.
I personally would suggest to save configId(data.value) into a state like:

```
<Dropdown
  ...
  onChange={this.show} /* better to rename it to something else cuz it's not just "show" any more */
/>

// save the configId(data.value) to state
show = (event, data) => this.setState({ open: true, selectedConfigId: data.value }); 

// get the value from state. You can also get "this.state.selectedConfigId" in this.handleConfigChange directly
handleConfirm = (e, data) => {
    this.handleConfigChange(e, this.state.selectedConfigId);
    this.setState({ open: false })
}
```